# Length Cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, eclipse, for-loop

I am new to Java and Android.

I have been getting this error in my program **length cannot be resolved or is not a field** I just don't understand how to solve this. 
Here's the code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;

public class DownloadImages extends AsyncTask {


protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
    System.out.println("External Storage State = " + Environment.getExternalStorageState());
    File directory=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Images");
    if (directory.exists()==false)
    {
        directory.mkdir();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <URLS.length; i++) {
        try {
            File firstFile=new File(directory+"/" +i+ ".jpeg");
            if(firstFile.exists()==false)
            {
                HttpClient httpClient =new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet =new HttpGet(URLS[i]);
                HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                System.out.println("Status Code = " +resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                if(resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
                {
                    HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
                    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                    Boolean status = firstFile.createNewFile();

                    FileOutputStream foutS = new FileOutputStream(firstFile);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    long total = 0;
                    int count;
                    while((count = is.read(buffer)) != -1){
                        total += count;
                        foutS.write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }
                    foutS.close();
                    is.close();
                    publishProgress(i);

                    }
                }

            }catch(MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    return null;
        }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values){
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }
}
```

**Getting Error in For Statement Line**

```
  for(int i = 0; i <URLS.length; i++) {
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.view.Menu;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity{

private static final String[] URLS = {
    "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_2851.jpg",
        "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_2944.jpg",
        "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_2989.jpg",
        "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3005.jpg",
        "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3012.jpg",
        "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3034.jpg",
        "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3047.jpg",
        "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3092.jpg",
        "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3110.jpg",
        "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3113.jpg",
        "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3128.jpg",
        "http://cdn.cs76.net/2011/spring/lectures/6/imgs/img_3160.jpg",
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new DownloadImages().execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting that error? What is your `URLS`?

Comment: This is the error: `URLS.length`.  What is "URLS"?????  Frankly, I'm surprised you're not getting a compiler error on "URLs" (never mind "URLS.length").  IMHO...

Comment: @Vulcan I have updated the question. I have created an inner class, which extends the AsyncTask. I dont know its inner class or not??
I dont know how to create an inner class in eclipse

Comment: The URLS array defined in `MainActivity` is `private`. It can't be the same `URLS` variable being used in `DownloadImages`, which seems to be a separate compilation unit. (At least, not if this code compiles successfully.)

Comment: Try declaring your `URLS` as `public` in your `MainActivity`.

Comment: @TedHopp Now what Should I do, to make it right And can you tell me how to cretae an inner class in eclipse.
Write ur answer plz

Comment: @RohitJain `protected` might be better

Comment: Is `DownloadImages` declared inside `MainActivity`?

Comment: @JanDvorak I changed to both protected and public but no changes

Comment: There are several ways to create an inner class in Eclipse. The easiest is to right click on the class file name in the Package Explorer, select New > Class, check the "Enclosing type" check box and make sure that the desired outer class is specified. (You can browse your project for the right one if you don't click on the one you want to start with.) Another way is to just type in the class declaration by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inner class is a class declared inside another class. Try putting `DownloadImages` inside `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

make URLS as public

```
public static final String[] URLS = {
```

and use it as

```
for(int i = 0; i <MainActivity.URLS.length; i++) {
```

Try it..,.

Comment: Or if they are in the same package, just remove the access modifier (to make it "package private").

Comment: thanks alot..!!
I just pasted Downloadimages.java to Main Activity and it worked.